# drilldown in highcharts by looping through arrays

Tags: javascript, highcharts, drilldown

I am trying to drill down the data with the javascript arrays I had, I have four arrays like

```
main_labels[]=[A,B,C,D,E]; // X Axis Labels
total_amounts[]=[10,11,12,13,14];
```

These are x and y axis that are shown when chart is loaded, now I have two    dimensional arrays like:

```
drill_data[0]=[A,B,C,D] 
// this is the data on drill down when I click A
drill_values[0]=[2,2,2,2,2] 
// the values that are to be shown on Y Axis when A is clicked,
```

In similar way I have separately dynamic generated arrays for B TO E, 
now I want to load corresponding array elements when B to E i clicked, 
the drilldown labels and values of B to E are like `drill_labels[1]`,
        `drill_values[1]`....`drill_values[4],drill_labels[4]`,

Can some one help me out about getting those drill_labels and drill_values array data to drill down, I am already done with loading the data on chart load

Comment: To have drilldown effect you need to parse your data to correct form like in the example: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown

Comment: Hello Sebastian, I have data in separate arrays, is there need to again re-format that into the way of the data in that link

Comment: You need to use javascript loops/conditions and parse, it is not built-in solution.

Comment: Hello Sestian, can you tell me one example please, I tried to that like charts.event({});, but I am unaware of the event, just tell me what the object/event top be called, I can write my own code